# ErrorException require(/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache, magento2

i have a Magento project when i run composer install i see this:

```
 [ErrorException]                                                                                                                   
  require(vendor/magento/framework/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

any help please?

Comment: try to delete vendor folder and run composer install

Comment: yes u'r right thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

The following steps resolved this error:

1. Delete vendor folder from project root: `rm -rf vendor`
2. Reinstall packages with composer: `composer install`